# Iterating (non-simultaneously) over multiple lists using purrr?

Tags: r, purrr

I want to create several data frames that are filtered using three variables in my dataset:
`state` is a categorical variable with two possible values -- `va` and `az`;
`log_aa_3r` and `log_lat_3r` are both continuous numeric variables.

I want to end up with 4 data frames: 2 for each state, and the dfs for each state will be filtered so that one has all cases where `log_aa_3r` is finite, and the other will have all cases where `log_lat_3r` is finite.

I can do this manually as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
az_aa <- combine_dat %>%
  filter(state == "az" & is.finite(log_aa_3r))

az_lat <- combine_dat %>%
  filter(state == "az" & is.finite(log_lat_3r))

va_aa <- combine_dat %>%
  filter(state == "va" & is.finite(log_aa_3r))

va_lat <- combine_dat %>%
  filter(state == "va" & is.finite(log_lat_3r))
```

However, I'd like to figure out how to do this iteratively.

I feel like I need to use nested map statements to solve this problem, but I can't quite seem to get the code right. I've tried the following, and it produces the output structure I expect, but all of the dfs in the outputs have 0 observations:

```
states <- list('az', 'va')
use_vars <- list('log_aa_3r', 'log_lat_3r')

dfs <- map(states, function(x)
           {map(use_vars,
                function(y) {comb_test %>%
                 filter(state == x & is.finite(y))}
                )}
           )
```

Here's a small set of data to help with the problem:

```
comb_test <- structure(list(state = c("az", "az", "va", "az", "az", "va", 
"va", "az", "va", "va", "az", "az", "az", "va", "az", "az", "va", 
"az", "az", "va"), log_aa_3r = c(0.122043015617762, NaN, 0.418616817019589, 
NaN, -0.237849698703905, 0.11553768471152, NA, -Inf, 0.253046912790677, 
0.71751672463271, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, 0.125839047001367, -Inf, 
0.372823951010564, 0.43784426926065, -Inf, -Inf, NA), log_lat_3r = c(0.0393482723090127, 
-0.352428653057281, -0.0641399653902218, -0.306485199414877, 
-0.696871579650928, -0.191460177039553, NA, -0.361114213161674, 
-0.0786756534620034, 0.216382765848136, 0.0344915670084646, 0.00130866713103227, 
0.756875541289108, NA, -0.216873938300614, -0.0627820764799239, 
0.261387831919094, -0.018314845703395, -0.161990655409072, NA
)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

I got it to work using the following code. It's maybe not the most elegant because I ended up having `tbl` names that were identical to variable names, but it does what I was trying to do.

```
df2 <- 
  map(states, function(x) 
{map_at(combine_test, c("log_aa_3r", "log_lat_3r"), function(y) 
{combine_test %>%
    filter(state == x & is.finite(y))})}
  )

df_list <- list(az_aa = df2[[1]]$log_aa_3r, az_lat = df2[[1]]$log_lat_3r, 
                va_aa = df2[[2]]$log_aa_3r, va_lat = df2[[2]]$log_lat_3r)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do this. First, you can generate all your conditions with `tidyr::crossing`

```
states <- c('az', 'va')
use_vars <- c('log_aa_3r', 'log_lat_3r')
conditions <- tidyr::crossing(states, use_vars)
```

Then you can use `purrr::pmap` to iterate over those two lists

```
purrr::pmap(conditions, function(states, use_vars) {
  comb_test %>% filter(state==!!(states) & is.finite(!!sym(use_vars)))
})
```

Here we use splicing (`!!`) to interject the values and use `sym()` to turn the string version of the variable name into a symbol

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't familiar with splicing or with the `sym` function. Your solution is way cleaner than the one I came up with.